# Could not find assembly System.Runtime issue is thrown when I tried to load project in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Below are the solution i tried to resolve the issue. But no luck.
I have deleted the bin and Obj folder and rebuild the solution.
I have removed the nuget reference in package.config and added again.

Any ideas or suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: what is the targetframework attribute in your nuget packages config file? Are projects under this solution targets to the same .NET Framework?

Comment: "Below is the solution", where is it?